# Problemas na inserção em duas tabelas PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Estou tentando fazer um INSERT em duas tabelas, primeiro preciso inserir as informações do veículo na tablea 'veiculo_cadastrado' e preciso inserir as imagens na tabela 'imagens_veiculo'. Está entrando no ELSE do primeiro INSERT, queria saber o que estou fazendo errado.

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once('conexao/conexao.php');

if(!empty($_POST['tipo_veiculo']) 
    && !empty($_POST['fabricante']) 
    && !empty($_POST['modelo']) 
    && !empty($_POST['valor_veiculo'])
    && !empty($_POST['placa_veiculo'])
    && !empty($_POST['renavam_veiculo'])
    && !empty($_POST['nome_documento'])){

    $id                      = $_SESSION['id_user'];
    $estado                  = $_POST['estado_veiculo'];
    $tipo                    = $_POST['tipo_veiculo'];
    $fabricante              = $_POST['fabricante'];
    $modelo                  = $_POST['modelo'];
    $ano_fabricacao          = $_POST['ano_fabricacao'];
    $ano_modelo              = $_POST['ano_modelo'];
    $cor                     = $_POST['cor_veiculo'];
    $combustivel             = $_POST['combustivel_veiculo'];
    $portas                  = $_POST['portas_veiculo'];
    $cambio                  = $_POST['cambio_veiculo'];
    $kilometragem            = $_POST['kilometragem_veiculo'];
    $dono                    = $_POST['dono_veiculo'];
    $cidade                  = $_POST['cidade_veiculo'];
    $valor                   = $_POST['valor_veiculo'];
    $descricao               = $_POST['descricao'];
    $placa                   = $_POST['placa_veiculo'];
    $renavam                 = $_POST['renavam_veiculo'];
    $nome_documento          = $_POST['nome_documento'];
    $alienado                = $_POST['alienado_veiculo'];
    $certificado             = $_POST['certificado_veiculo'];
    $garantia                = $_POST['garantia_veiculo'];
    $ipva                    = $_POST['ipva_veiculo'];
    $licenciado              = $_POST['licenciado_veiculo'];
    $revisoes                = $_POST['revisoes_veiculo'];
    $revisoes_concessionaria = $_POST['revisoes_concessionaria'];

    //INFO IMAGEM
    $file       = $_FILES['img'];
    $numFile    = count(array_filter($file['name']));

    //PASTA
    $folder     = '../images/veiculos';

    //REQUISITOS
    $permite    = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png');
    $maxSize    = 1024 * 1024 * 10;

    //MENSAGENS
    $msg        = array();
    $errorMsg   = array(
        1 => 'O arquivo enviado excede o limite definido na diretiva upload_max_filesize do php.ini.',
        2 => 'O arquivo excede o limite definido em MAX_FILE_SIZE no formulário HTML.',
        3 => 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente.',
        4 => 'Nenhum arquivo foi enviado.',
        6 => 'Pasta temporária ausênte.',
        7 => 'Falha em escrever o arquivo em disco.',
        8 => 'Uma extensão do PHP interrompeu o upload do arquivo.'
    );

    $query = "INSERT INTO veiculo_cadastrado
                (id_user,
                estado_veiculo,
                tipo_cadastro,
                fabricante_veiculo,
                modelo_veiculo,
                ano_fabricacao,
                ano_modelo,
                cor_veiculo,
                combutivel_veiculo,
                portas_veiculo,
                cambio_veiculo,
                kilometragem_veiculo,
                dono_veiculo,
                cidade_veiculo,
                valor_veiculo,
                descricao_veiculo,
                placa_veiculo,
                renavam_veiculo,
                nome_documento,
                alienado_veiculo,
                certificado_veiculo,
                garantia_veiculo,
                ipva_veiculo,
                licenciado_veiculo,
                revisoes_veiculo,
                revisoes_concessionaria)
                VALUES
                ('{$id}',
                '{$estado}',
                '{$tipo}',
                '{$fabricante}',
                '{$modelo}',
                '{$ano_fabricacao}',
                '{$ano_modelo}',
                '{$cor}',
                '{$combustivel}',
                '{$portas}',
                '{$cambio}',
                '{$kilometragem}',
                '{$dono}',
                '{$cidade}',
                '{$valor}',
                '{$descricao}',
                '{$placa}',
                '{$renavam}',
                '{$nome_documento}',
                '{$alienado}',
                '{$certificado}',
                '{$garantia}',
                '{$ipva}',
                '{$licenciado}',
                '{$revisoes}',
                '{$revisoes_concessionaria}')";

    $insereVeiculo  = mysql_query($query, $con);

    if($insereVeiculo){
        $_SESSION['certo'] = "Inserido com sucesso";
        $last = mysql_insert_id();
    } else{
        $msg = "Ocorreu um erro";

    }


    if($numFile <= 0)
        $_SESSION['aviso'] = 'Selecione uma imagem!';
    else{
        for($i = 0; $i < $numFile; $i++){
            $name   = $file['name'][$i];
            $type   = $file['type'][$i];
            $size   = $file['size'][$i];
            $error  = $file['error'][$i];
            $tmp    = $file['tmp_name'][$i];        

            $extensao = @end(explode('.', $name));
            $novoNome = rand().".$extensao";

            if($error != 0)
                $msg[] = "<b>$name : </b>".$errorMsg[$error];
            else if(!in_array($type, $permite))
                $msg[] = "<b>$name : </b> Erro imagem não suportada!";
            else if($size > $maxSize)
                $msg[] = "<b>$name : </b> Imagem ultrapassa limite de 10MB";
            else{

                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder."/".$novoNome))
                    $msg[] = "<b>$name : </b> Upload realizado com sucesso!";
                else{
                    $msg[] = "<b>$name : </b> Desculpe ocorreu um erro!";
                }

            }

        $insert = "INSERT INTO imagens_veiculo 
                    (id_veiculo,
                    imagem_veiculo)
                    VALUES 
                    ('{$last}',
                    '{$novoNome}')";
        $exe_insert = mysql_query($insert, $con);

        }


    }


} else{
    $msg = "Preencha todos os campos";
}

echo $msg;
```

**Formulario**

```html
<form method="post" action="php/insereVeiculo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="col-xs-12">
 <div class="text-top-form">
  <h2><i class="fa fa-car" aria-hidden="true"></i> Veículo</h2>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="estado_veiculo" value="Novo">Novo</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="estado_veiculo" value="Usado">Usado</label>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
 <div class="form-group">
  <span class="obr">Tipo: *</span>
  <select name="tipo_veiculo" class="form-control option-bold custom-field">
   <option selected>-</option>
   <?php while($row_tipo_veiculo = mysql_fetch_assoc($tipo_veiculo)){ ?>
    <option><?php echo $row_tipo_veiculo['tipo_veiculo']; ?></option>
   <?php } ?>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
 <div class="form-group">
  <span class="obr">Fabricante: *</span>
  <select id="fabricante" name="fabricante" class="form-control option-bold custom-field">
   <option selected>-</option>
   <?php while($row_marcas = mysql_fetch_assoc($marcas)){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_marcas['id'] ?>"><?php echo $row_marcas['nome']; ?></option>
   <?php } ?>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
     
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="pot">
 <div class="form-group">
  <span class="obr">Veículo: *</span>
  <select id="modelo" name="modelo" class="form-control option-bold custom-field">
   <option disabled selected>Selecione o Fabricante</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
 <div class="form-group">
  <span class="obr">Ano de Fabricação: *</span>
  <select name="ano_fabricacao" class="form-control custom-field option-bold">
   <option selected>-</option>
   <option>2017</option>
   <option>2016</option>
   <option>2015</option>
   <option>2014</option>
   <option>2013</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
    
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
 <div class="form-group">
  <span class="obr">Ano do Modelo: *</span>
  <select name="ano_modelo" class="form-control custom-field option-bold">
   <option selected>-</option>
   <option>2017</option>
   <option>2016</option>
   <option>2015</option>
   <option>2014</option>
   <option>2013</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
       <div class="form-group">
         <span class="obr">Cor: </span>
         <select name="cor_veiculo" class="form-control custom-field option-bold">
          <option selected>-</option>
          <option>Branco</option>
          <option>Roxo</option>
          <option>Preto</option>
          <option>Cinza</option>
         </select>
       </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
       <div class="form-group">
         <span class="obr">Combustível: *</span>
         <select name="combustivel_veiculo" class="form-control custom-field option-bold">
          <option selected>-</option>
          <option>Gasolina</option>
          <option>Alcool</option>
          <option>Diesel</option>
          <option>Flex</option>
          <option>Gás</option>
         </select>
       </div>
      </div>
     
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
       <div class="form-group">
         <span class="obr">Portas: </span>
         <select name="portas_veiculo" class="form-control custom-field option-bold">
          <option selected>-</option>
          <option>1P</option>
          <option>2P</option>
          <option>3P</option>
          <option>4P</option>
         </select>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
       <div class="form-group">
         <span class="obr">Câmbio: *</span>
         <select name="cambio_veiculo" class="form-control custom-field option-bold">
          <option selected>-</option>
          <option>Manual</option>
          <option>Automático</option>
          <option>CVT</option>
         </select>
       </div>
      </div>
     
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
       <div class="form-group">
        <span class="obr">kilometragem: *</span>
        <input type="text" name="kilometragem_veiculo" class="form-control custom-field" placeholder="-" >
       </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
       <div class="form-group">
        <span class="obr">Dono: </span>
        <select name="dono_veiculo" class="form-control custom-field option-bold">
         <option selected>-</option>
         <option>Único Dono</option>
         <option>Segundo Dono</option>
         <option>Mais de dois donos</option>
        </select>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
       <div class="form-group">
        <span class="obr">Cidade do Veículo: *</span>
        <input type="text" name="cidade_veiculo" class="form-control custom-field" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cidade_user']; ?>">
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-12">
       <div class="text-top-form">
        <h2><i class="fa fa-money" aria-hidden="true"></i> Valor de Venda</h2>
       </div>
      </div>
     
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
       <div class="form-group">
        <span class="obr">Valor: *</span>
        <input type="text" name="valor_veiculo" class="form-control custom-field" placeholder="-" >
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding">
       <div class="text-top-form">
        <h2><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i> Descrição</h2>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-12">
       <textarea name="descricao" class="custom-field-textarea form-control" style="height: 250px;"></textarea>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding" style="margin-top: 15px;">
      <div class="text-top-form">
       <h2><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Documentação do Veículo</h2>
      </div>
     </div>
     
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
       <div class="form-group">
        <span class="obr">Placa: </span>
        <input type="text" name="placa_veiculo" class="form-control custom-field" placeholder="-" >
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
       <div class="form-group">
        <span class="obr">Renavam:</span>
        <input type="text" name="renavam_veiculo" class="form-control custom-field" placeholder="-" >
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
       <div class="form-group">
        <span class="obr">Nome Documento</span>
        <input type="text" name="nome_documento" class="form-control custom-field" placeholder="-" >
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
       <div class="radio" style="border:0; margin-top: 10px;">
        <label>
         <input type="radio" name="alienado_veiculo" value="Alienado">
          <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></span>
          Alienado
        </label>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
       <div class="radio" style="border:0; margin-top: 10px;">
        <label>
         <input type="radio" name="certificado_veiculo" value="Com Certificado">
          <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></span>
          Com Certificado
        </label>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
       <div class="radio" style="border:0; margin-top: 10px;">
        <label>
         <input type="radio" name="garantia_veiculo" value="Garantia de Fabrica">
          <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></span>
          Garantia de Fábrica
        </label>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
       <div class="radio" style="border:0;">
        <label>
         <input type="radio" name="ipva_veiculo" value="IPVA Pago">
          <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></span>
          IPVA Pago
        </label>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
       <div class="radio" style="border:0;">
        <label>
         <input type="radio" name="licenciado_veiculo" value="Licenciado">
          <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></span>
          Licenciado
        </label>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
       <div class="radio" style="border:0;">
        <label>
         <input type="radio" name="revisoes_veiculo" value="Todas revisões feitas pela agenda do carro">
          <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></span>
          Todas revisões feitas pela agenda do carro 
        </label>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
       <div class="radio" style="border:0;">
        <label>
         <input type="radio" name="revisoes_concessionaria" value="Todas revisões feitas pela concessionária">
          <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></span>
          Todas revisões feitas pela concessionária
        </label>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding">
       <div class="text-top-form">
        <h2><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Imagens Veículo</h2>
       </div>
      </div>
      
       <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 nopadding">
                              <div class="form-group uploadImages">
                                 <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">
                                    ENVIE AS IMAGENS<br>
                                    <small> Selecione as imagens do seu veículo.</small>
                                 </label>
                                 <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                                    <div id="upload-ad-images" class="dropzone"></div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
       </div>
      
      <input class="button-new-anuncio btn-default" type="submit" name="img[]" value="Adicionar Anúncio" />
   
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o erro esteja aqui :

> if($insereVeiculo)

sobre insert mysql_query não retorna true para conseguir isso deve usar o comando

> mysql_affected_rows

para analisar quantas linhas foram afetadas.

mysql_query : http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-query.php

Para comandos SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE ou EXPLAIN, mysql_query() retorna um resource em caso de sucesso, ou FALSE em caso de falha.

Para outros tipos de consultas SQL, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() retorna TRUE em caso de sucesso ou FALSE em caso de erro.

O recurso de resultado retornado pode ser passado para mysql_fetch_array(), e outras funções para manipular tabelas de resultados, para acessar os dados retornados.

Use mysql_num_rows() para obter quantas linhas foram retornadas para um comando SELECT ou mysql_affected_rows() para obter quantas linhas foram afetadas por um comando DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, ou UPDATE.

mysql_query() irá também falhar e retornar FALSE se o usuário não tiver permissões para acessar a tabela(s) referenciadas pela consulta.

mysql_affected_rows  : http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Comment: Fiz essa alteração e percebi que ele apenas executa o primeiro INSERT, mas ele da o retorno de que "Ocorreu um erro" só que faz o INSERT corretamente no banco. No segundo INSERT ele para no "Selecione uma imagem"

Comment: Altera a pergunta e post o código html com o formulário de upload.